# SwiftUI: Limit width of Text in VStack without making it grow unnecessarily

Tags: swiftui

I want to limit the width of a Text to a given number. I thought that using `frame(maxWidth:)` would do the job, however it does not behave as expected at all. It seems that setting a max width makes the text grow to this size, whatever the size it should be.

Here's a code snippet:

```
    VStack(spacing: 20) {
        VStack {
            Text("Some Text")
                .frame(maxWidth: 200)
        }
        .background(Color.yellow)
        .border(.black, width: 1)

        VStack {
            Text("A longer text that should wrap to the next line.")
                .frame(maxWidth: 200)
        }
        .background(Color.yellow)
        .border(.black, width: 1)
    }
```

Expected result:

[image: Expected result]

Actual result:

[image: Actual result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, `Text` automatically grow/shrink by itself. To solve your problem, just set maxWidth to your `VStack` instead of `Text` to control your maxWidth, then add backgrounds modifiers to your text instead.
Code is below the image:
[image]

```
    VStack(spacing: 20) {
           VStack {
               Text("Some Text")
                   .background(Color.yellow)
                   .border(.black, width: 1)
           }
           .frame(maxWidth: 200)

           VStack {
               Text("A longer text that should wrap to the next line.")
               .background(Color.yellow)
               .border(.black, width: 1)
           }
           .frame(maxWidth: 200)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that we need a generic component which should work similarly with specified behavior independently of provided string, like

```
VStack(spacing: 20) {
   TextBox("Some Text")
       .background(Color.yellow)
       .border(.black, width: 1)

   TextBox("A longer text that should wrap to the next line.")
       .background(Color.yellow)
       .border(.black, width: 1)
}
```

then some run-time calculations required.

Here is a demo of possible solution (with real edge markers). Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[image: demo]

Main part:

```
struct TextBox: View {
    private let string: LocalizedStringKey
    private let maxWidth: CGFloat

    @State private var width: CGFloat

    init(_ text: LocalizedStringKey, maxWidth: CGFloat = 200) {  // << any default value
        // ... 
    }

    // ... 

        Text(string)
            .background(GeometryReader {
                Color.clear
                    .preference(key: ViewSideLengthKey.self, value: $0.frame(in: .local).size.width)
            })
            .onPreferenceChange(ViewSideLengthKey.self) {
                self.width = min($0, maxWidth)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: width)
```

[Test code on GitHub](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestTextUpToBoxLimit.swift)

Answer (score 1):

The `VStack` adjusts its `width` to the max `width` of its elements. This is the native behavior of the `VStack`.

However, if you do the following you'll get the result you want:

```
VStack(spacing: 20) {
    VStack {
        Text("Some Text")
            .background(Color.yellow)
            .border(.black, width: 1)
    }.frame(maxWidth: 200)
    VStack {
        Text("A longer text that should wrap to the next line.")
            .frame(maxWidth: 200)
    }.background(Color.yellow)
        .border(.black, width: 1)
}
```